# How do I find the name of Perl module when using apt-get?

Tags: perl, apt

Perl modules are named differently when using `apt-get`.

How do I find out the corresponding naming for a module that needs to be installed when using `apt-get`?

For example:

`use Sort::Key::Natural qw(natsort)` is named something different in `apt-get`

Answer (score 6):

The name of the Debian/Ubuntu/... package is derived from the name of the Perl distribution.

[`Sort::Key::Natural`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural) is part of the [`Sort-Key`](https://metacpan.org/dist/Sort-Key) distribution. You can find the distro name (`Sort-Key`) by visiting the CPAN page for the module (first link). It's at the very top, after the name of the author.

To obtain the Debian/Ubuntu/... package name, lowercase the Perl distro name, prefix with `lib`, and suffix with `-perl`.<sup>[1]</sup> This gives us `libsort-key-perl`.

---

Alternatively, you could also look for the package that provides `Sort/Key/Natural.pm`.<sup>[2]</sup> One way of doing this:

```bash
apt-file search Sort/Key/Natural.pm
```

---

1. As obtained using `"lib" . lc( $distro ) . "-perl"`.
2. As obtained using `( $module =~ s{::}{/}gr ) . ".pm"`.

Comment: Heh, I guess the answer is "you ask ikegami" :) There was an old story about a csh to perl converter where you posted your script on usenet and would get a perl script back. It was just @tchrist rewriting it and posting it. Even if it's not true, I want it to be true.

Comment: The command apt-get exists in my machine but not apt-file search. How do I add apt-file? Thanks!

Comment: `sudo apt install apt-file`

Comment: Why Graphics::DZI doesn't exist with apt-get. I tried libgraphics-dzi-perl and fails `apt-get install -y libgraphics-dzi-perl`

Comment: You'll have to ask the source of your packages about that.

Comment: This is Graphics::DZI -- who is the source of my packages?

Comment: `apt-get install -y libimage-magick-perl`  followed by `cpan Graphics::DZI`. Why is that? Seems convoluted to me.

Comment: Actually I am getting this error: `Undefined subroutine &Graphics::DZI called at tile_image.pl line 9.` Why is that?

Comment: Re "*who is the source of my packages?*", You never told us

Comment: Re "*Why is that?*", I can't comment on code I haven't seen. And the comments is not the place to ask new questions.